# How can I make kotlin realize this BST compare function is tail recursive?

Tags: kotlin

Here is a simple Binary Search Tree class that I put together.

```
data class Bst<T: Comparable<T>>(var left: Bst<T>?, var value: T, var right: Bst<T>?) {
    tailrec fun contains(key: T): Boolean {
        return if (key < value) {
            left?.contains(key) ?: false
        } else if (key > value) {
            right?.contains(key) ?: false
        } else {
            true
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I paste this into [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org), it says that the recursive calls are not tail-recursive. If I refactor the `left?.contains` code into an if statement that tests for `left == null`, it comes up with another error about how `left` is mutable and could have changed since the `if` statement. How can I make these calls tail recursive in the eyes of kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Like stated in [Tail recursive functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions):

> To be eligible for the `tailrec` modifier, a function must call itself as the last operation it performs. You cannot use tail recursion when there is more code after the recursive call, and you cannot use it within try/catch/finally blocks.

There your implementation fails already with the first constraint to call the function itself again. Even though you call this function, it's at another instance and also not the last operation of this block.

The best I could come up with was implementing it *"statically"* in the *Kotlin* context.

```
data class Bst<T: Comparable<T>>(var left: Bst<T>?, var value: T, var right: Bst<T>?) {
    fun contains(key: T) = contains(key, this)

    companion object {
        tailrec fun <T: Comparable<T>> contains(key: T, bst: Bst<T>): Boolean {
            if (key == bst.value) return true
            val bst2 = bst.run { if (key < value) left else right }
            if (bst2 == null) return false
            return contains(key, bst2)
        }
    }
}
```

But additionally you should consider to implement a null-value pattern, instead of using nullable values for left and right. You could utilize [Sealed Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) for this.